# Cannot get data in PHP from JQuery Ajax post with JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, http-post

I am trying a simple test to learn about the JQuery Ajax POST method and I have setup a little example on my server. However I can't it to work.

My JavaScript is as follows:

JavaScript:

```
var json = {"Num String":"2","Num":3,"Num":11,"Num":2,"Num":"?"};
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sampleJSONPost.php",
        data: json, //Data to POST to the server
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
            console.log("Error " + err + " " + status + " " + JSON.stringify(jqXHR)); //Log the Error 
        },
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {  
              console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); //Log the Data returned
              $("span").text(data);
        }
    });
};
```

And here is my PHP:

PHP:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST["data"];
echo json_decode($data);
?>
```

However this always gives me the following error:

```
Error SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input parsererror {"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

So to me it looks like my $data variable in PHP is not getting the JSON I am sending with the POST, would this be correct? If so can anyone help me find what is wrong? I have already tried lots of other solutions from SO but without success so I must be missing something simple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change into

```
var json = {"data":{"Num String":"2","Num":3,"Num":11,"Num":2,"Num":"?"}};
```

Comment: Or at server side $data = $_POST;

Comment: remove dataType: "json" line from your ajax config

Comment: and contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", also

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
      data: json,
```

to

```
    data: JSON.stringify({ json : json }),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var json = {{"Num String":"2"},{"Num":3},{"Num":11},{"Num":2}};
```

or

This, I am not checking

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'sampleJSONPost.php',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: { "Num String":"2","Num":3,"Num":11,"Num":2,"Num":"?" },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
{

},
    error: AjaxFailed
});
```